MC Server Screen issues
I currently just set up my first MC server using ubuntu server and while I can get into the screen, I cannot do anything in the screen, all I get is just the logs for the server. how can I regain control of my server?

There is a lot of possible software with the initials MC. One assumes you might mean Minecraft. If so, please edit your question to include exactly which Minecraft Server application (Java? Something else?) and which release of Ubuntu. Also clarify what you mean by "the screen." Do you mean the Screen application? Or the Minecraft application running inside the Screen application? Or connect a player to the server? What are you trying to accomplish or change by "regaining control?" There might be an easier way. If you followed instructions to create the server, provide a link.
